# Running node.js server with mongodb error

Tags: node.js

I'm still new to node.js and mongodb. Now I'm trying to solve this problem.

I have instructions to run my server without any problems, I follow them and yes my server works. But when I switched the server off then run it again I face this bug:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ node /opt/inapsrv/app/app.js 
app-api listening at http://0.0.0.0:7000

/opt/inapsrv/node_modules/fileupload/lib/modules/file.js:23
  throw error
        ^
Error: ENOENT, mkdir 'data/imagex/'
```

And here is the line of the directory above taken from app.js file:

```
var imagePath = 'data/imagex/';
```

I tried to:

- make vagrant and mongo users as super users and they have the root permissions.
- to run "sudo node /opt/inapsrv/app/app.js"
- run "forever /opt/inapsrv/app/app.js"

and it didn't work.

I don't know why it successfully ran the first time, and then it didn't!
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're using node module [fileupload](https://github.com/domharrington/fileupload) for the upload job. The source code fragment in fileupload that throws your error can be found [here](https://github.com/domharrington/fileupload/blob/master/lib/modules/file.js).

The problem with the code used in fileupload module is that it does not create recursive directories since `fs.mkdir` is used. To fix your issue try to create the upload directory or at least `data` upfront. You could do this by a npm script, in app.js using the [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mkdirp) or simply by a shell script.

The problem described is not related to mongodb or mongoose.

Comment: thank you, it solved my problem finally. I added this line before executing the forever command "sudo mkdir -p data/imagex"